# Android studio design mode

Tags: java, android

Today I've installed Android studio and started learning app development. But I can't add buttons and other stuff to my design because the window has a weird appearance. Check out the screenshot. https://prnt.sc/k9w4pd  The buttons seem to be adding but I can't see them. How to make this right?

Comment: share your xml code.

Comment: Android Layout Editor preview does not work until successful build. Try to build. Fix errors if any.

Comment: Build the project first

Answer (score 0):

This is a Render Error if you click on the red exclamation mark in the top right corner, you will see the errormessage below the designer.

The cause of your error is probably that you have to add the coordinatorLayoutStyle in your theme in values/styles.xml

```
<item name="coordinatorLayoutStyle">@style/Widget.Design.CoordinatorLayout</item>
```

or change the build.gradle file in your project with:

```
implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0-alpha1'
```

in dependencies

Comment: Still fighting with this problem. I updated styles.xml but check out my error: https://prnt.sc/k9wtb4

Comment: Have you tried the second solution aswell, its probably better.
If you want to use the first add the design implementation: 

implementation 'com.android.support:design:28.0.0-alpha1'